# Same File Opened multiple times when Downloading from IE 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, download

I have implemented one file downloading function using MVC. The function is working fine on my local. In some machine when try this function using IE8, it still give the dialog let user choose open or download , the issue is When choose open, the file will open multiple times. The MVC is deployed in Windows 2008 server and IIS7.5.
Is this an issue of my implementation or some configuration of IE?
My download code is like this:

```
public async Task<FilePathResult> Index()
    {
        var virtualFilePath = await Task.Run(() => GetFile(token));
        return File(virtualFilePath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, Path.GetFileName(virtualFilePath));
    }
```

The `GetFile` method will return the file path.in our case it is a share folder path.
If any knows this, please give your comments, thanks in advance.